# Encountering remote error using grpc with protobuf2.6 in python

Tags: python-2.7, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am using grpc with protobuf 2.6.1 in python 2.7, and when I run my client side code, I have the following errors:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "debate_client.py", line 31, in <module>
 run_client()
 File "debate_client.py", line 17, in run_client
 reply = stub.Answer(debate_pb2.AnswerRequest(question=question, timeout=timeout), 30)
 File "/Users/elaine/Desktop/gitHub/grpc/python2.7_virtual_environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grpc/framework/crust/implementations.py", line 73, in __call__
 protocol_options, metadata, request)
 File "/Users/elaine/Desktop/gitHub/grpc/python2.7_virtual_environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grpc/framework/crust/_calls.py", line 109, in blocking_unary_unary
 return next(rendezvous)
 File "/Users/elaine/Desktop/gitHub/grpc/python2.7_virtual_environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grpc/framework/crust/_control.py", line 412, in next
 raise self._termination.abortion_error
 grpc.framework.interfaces.face.face.RemoteError: RemoteError(code=StatusCode.UNKNOWN, details="")
```

Here is my client side code:

```
from grpc.beta import implementations
import debate_pb2
import sys

def run_client():
    params = sys.argv
    print params
    how = params[1]
    question = params[2]

    channel = implementations.insecure_channel('localhost', 29999)
    stub = debate_pb2.beta_create_Candidate_stub(channel)
    if how.lower() == "answer":
        timeout = int(params[3])
        reply = stub.Answer(debate_pb2.AnswerRequest(question=question, timeout=timeout), 30)

    elif how.lower() == "elaborate":
        blah = params[3:len(sys.argv)]
        for i in range(0, len(blah)):
            blah[i] = int(blah[i])
        reply = stub.Elaborate(debate_pb2.ElaborateRequest(topic=question, blah_run=blah), 30)

    if reply is None:
        print "No comment"
    else:
        print reply.answer

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_client()
```

And here is my server side code:

```
import debate_pb2
import consultation_pb2
import re
import random
from grpc.beta import implementations


class Debate(debate_pb2.BetaCandidateServicer):

    def Answer(self, request, context=None):
        #Answer implementation
    def Elaborate(self, request, context=None):
        #Elaborate implementation

def run_server():
    server = debate_pb2.beta_create_Candidate_server(Debate())
    server.add_insecure_port('localhost:29999')
    server.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_server()
```

Any idea where the remote error comes from? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Hello Elaine and thank you for trying out gRPC Python.

Nothing leaps out at me as an obvious smoking gun, but a couple of things I see are:

1. gRPC Python isn't known to work with protobuf 2.6.1. Have you tried working with the very latest protobuf release (3.0.0a3 at this time)?
2. `context` isn't an optional keyword parameter in servicer methods; it's a required, positional parameter. Does dropping `=None` from your servicer method implementations effect any change?

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me just now, and I figured out why.

Make sure the messages in your proto definition and the message in your implementations match the format.

For example, my `Response` message had a `message=` param in my python server, but not in my proto definition.

Answer (score 0):

I think your function implementations should be outside `class Debate` or might be your functions are not correctly implemented to give the desired result.

I faced a similar error because my functions were inside the class but moving it outside the class fixed it.